# Adding an object with a null ArrayList to my repository

Tags: java, jpa, arraylist, nullpointerexception, many-to-many

This is my first question, and I'm a total noob. Been working in Java for 3 months, so be gentle. I'm doing an online registry tracking weddings and users. Users can have multiple weddings and vice versa. It's essentially a many to many relationship but I'm trying another route: embedding the User and Wedding Classes with Array Lists of each other. Like so.

```
    package com.theironyard.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by macbookair on 12/8/15.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "weddings")
public class Wedding {

    public ArrayList <User> guests;
    // ArrayList here is to store users associated with Wedding. 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
     public int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String weddingName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String location;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String date;


    public Wedding(){
    }

    public Wedding(String date, String location, String weddingName, int id) {
        this.date = date;
        this.location = location;
        this.weddingName = weddingName;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Wedding(ArrayList guests) {
        this.guests = guests;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public ArrayList getGuests() {
        return guests;
    }

    public void setGuests(ArrayList guests) {
        this.guests = guests;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWeddingName() {
        return weddingName;
    }

    public void setWeddingName(String weddingName) {
        this.weddingName = weddingName;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And the User Class

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
public class User {

    public ArrayList<Wedding>userWeddings;
    // Array List to store weddings associated with user. 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String phone;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(ArrayList<Wedding> userWeddings) {
        this.userWeddings = userWeddings;
    }

    public User(int id, String username, String phone, String email, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;

    }

    public ArrayList<Wedding> getUserWeddings() {
        return userWeddings;
    }

    public void setUserWeddings(ArrayList<Wedding> userWeddings) {
        this.userWeddings = userWeddings;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

Then I run a "/create wedding" route which adds the Wedding and User to eachother's ArrayList. The goal is that later on we can reference who is going to what wedding, and one person can see all the weddings they're associated with like so:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/create-wedding", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Wedding createWedding(@RequestBody Wedding wedding, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
    weddings.save(wedding);

    User user = users.findOneByEmail((String) session.getAttribute("email"));
    if (user == null) {
        throw new Exception("User does not exist");
    }
    wedding.guests.add(user);
```

// adding user to "guests" array List in Wedding class.

```
    Invite invite =  new Invite();
    invite.isAdmin= true;
    invite.wedding= wedding;
    invite.email = user.email;
    user.userWeddings.add(wedding); // adding user to List in "User class"

    return wedding;
}
```

but I'm getting a Null-Pointer Exception because the Array Lists are null. I was under the impression that if I didn't explicitly say they were non-nullable then by default they would be. I considered adding the (nullable = true) annotation but I don't seem to be able to do that without making it a column within the database.

Basically, I can't add the User/Wedding objects because the embedded ArrayLists are null. Even working around this, would there be a simpler way to allow for multiple Users to every Wedding and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare JPA [@ManyToMany](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html) annotation which defines the relationship between User and Wedding entities. (above two fields)

Then, if you don't have to maintain any Order for weddings in User or users in Wedding, you can use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface instead of List (ArrayList in your example) for both sides of this bi-directional relationship.

Note: when this mapping is properly defined you never get null values for Collection type fields involved in relationships with other entity from a managed entity (already persisted, not detached)

See also [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#JEETT00671).